# Evaluating a Django Query : Using python's .index() on a Django Query [values_list(Flat=True)]

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out what is the rank of a django model object within objects that meet the same criterias.

My idea was to get a flat values_list of primary keys like this:

[In the models.py page, in the Model "Risk", other linked models are Worktask and Type]

```
my_list_of_filtered_pks = Risk.objects.filter(
        worktask__code = self.worktask.code,
        type__id = self.type.id
    ).values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('pk')
```

And then get the index of my particular instance using something like:

```
rank = my_list_of_filtered_pks.index(self.pk)
```

But i get an error saying that my my_list_of_filtered_pks has no attribute 'index'

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'index'
```

What am i missing here ?

Thanks ! i'm relatively new to django .. !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queryset has not been evaluated yet. Try this:

```
rank = list(my_list_of_filtered_pks).index(self.pk)
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Comment: Got it ! It works. 
I hadn't realized that when i was calling count() on it earlier (to make sure the query worked) it was actually evaluating it only then.
Thanks ! How would you edit the title to make the question more understandable to others ?